# How Change color of the textbox foreground after select or tap on the textbox in UWP c#?

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, uwp, uwp-xaml

How Change color of the textbox foreground after select or tap on the textbox in UWP?

i used below code on gotfocus event of textbox.

```
private void tbWeight_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
  tbWeight.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.blue); 
}
```

First time when i write some thing on textbox its work fine 
but when textbox lost focus and then tap or get the cursor again on the same textbox the font color is get change to black.
I want change black color to blue or any other color.

Comment: could you provide more code?

Comment: private void tbWeight_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {  tbWeight.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.blue);  }

Comment: is any thing wrong..

Answer (score 0):

> is any thing wrong

When you set `Foreground` property to a `TextBox`, this color will only be applied when the `TextBox` lost focus, so when you get cursor of it, this color will not be changed. This is why your code works at the first time.

Then in the `LostFocus` event you change the foreground to its original color. It makes your foreground changes when got focus and changes again DIRECTLY when lost focus, but the foreground color will only be applied when the `TextBox` lost focus, it makes your code then seems like never works.

The right way to do this work is to modify the template of `TextBox`, you can open the **Document Outline** then find your `TextBox`, right click it and choose **Edit Template**, finally select **Edit a copy**, the default style of your `TextBox` will then be generated in the `Page.Resources`. In this style, you can find the `VisualState x:Name="Focused"`, under this visual state, it controls the foreground of `TextBox` when it got focused, you can change it for example like this:

```
<VisualState x:Name="Focused">
    <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForegroundFocused}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundFocused}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrushFocused}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Blue" /> <!--This one here!-->
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="RequestedTheme" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Light" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

Comment: @TrishitBera, maybe I've a little misunderstood your problem, but even you set the foreground, when the `TextBox` got focus, the foreground will return to be the original color, it is defined in the visual state...This is why I suggested you to edit the visual state in the template of `TextBox`.

Comment: is Their any simple way for this problem.Because its fill my xaml page. :)

Comment: @TrishitBera, you can override the `SystemControlForegroundChromeBlackHighBrush` in your app.xaml, but this will change the whole system brush. Or you can modify this with vs blend, this operation may be easier for some guys, but eventually this value should be modified, AFAIK, this is already the easiest way...

Comment: Thank you for help and time.. :)